# lost symbols with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

I am trying to typeset my text and math latin/greek in Georgia, and digits (math mode) in Neo Euler.

I am using XeLaTeX with `unicode-math`. MWE below loses ldots, also the star and minus operators, and instead of {,} I get Euler's f and g. Also, no mathbf. Any pointers?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Georgia-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}, bold-style=TeX]{Neo Euler}

\begin{document}    
    Answer: $(1+00)^*=\{1, \mathbf{00}, 001, 100, 10000, \ldots \}$\\
    and $b^2= 22 \times 22$, whereas $\alpha-\epsilon=90^\circ$.
\end{document}
```

[image: Example results in loss of symbols]

MikTeX 2.9, fontspec 2013/02/25 v2.3, unicode-math 2013/05/04 v0.7e.

Comment: Additional to Enrico's answer you should be aware of the fact that Neo Euler isn't really complete, a lot of symbols are missing.

Comment: I see... so how does one keep CM for symbols?

Comment: use `\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not defining a main math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Georgia-Italic}

\begin{document}    
Answer: $(1+00)^*=\{1, \mathbf{00}, 001, 100, 10000, \ldots \}$\\
and $b^2= 22 \times 22$, whereas $\alpha-\epsilon=90^\circ$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I really need to force myself to really understand how fontspec/unicode-math works, it's always like groping in the dark, using snippets from here and there.